# Which studio light setup to for this linked image of a dog

Tags: studio-lighting

maybe one or the other knows the german photographer Elke Vogelsang, who specialized herself in dog photography. From an interview she gave, I read she is using two strip lights and one round umbrella to get her desired lighting.

As I really like the style of her pictures and I got a dalmatian dog these weeks, I want to try to take some images in a similar look.

[Here are some example images, especially the one above the one with the CAT post it on the forhead.](http://www.boredpanda.com/expressive-dog-portraits-elke-vogelsang/)

As I am not experienced in studio photography, my question is now how to set up the lights to achieve this look. My guess Is the umbrella in front of and above the dog (one can see the reflections of it in the dog's eyes) and the two strip lights on each side behind the dogs. I also would guess the umbrella has to be a bit weaker than the two strip lights, to keep some shadows on the front side of the dogs.

What do you think?

Edit: [I found a lighting example (the second image) with two strip lights](http://portrait-photographer.blogspot.co.at/2010/03/why-are-strip-lights-so-cool.html), which strengthen my guess...

Edit2: Thanks for all the comments! I am really only referring to the lighting. For sure, all the other aspects are equally or even more important to achieve the final result, but this question is only about the light setup.

Comment: What lighting do you have available? Personally i'd say these images are less about creative lighting and more about the subject. Looking at the images and reflections in the eyes, she potentially she could have just got away with a big old soft light above camera.

Comment: I'd have said they rely heavily on the relatively close focus (wide-ish angle) to get a look, as well as choosing shots where the dogs are making some extreme mouth movements.  I find them somewhat contrived, but YMMV.

Comment: Can you explain what "like these" means to you? See [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions). Please put some of that description into the title of the question as well — as it is, the same title could apply to millions of different situations, and that's not very useful.

Comment: i think another important effect, apart from lighting, is shallow depth of field and "wide lens" perspective with enlarged dog noses. This probably achieved here by using something like 50mm f/1.8 or more likely 24mm f/1.4 .As you know, depth of field is larger with wider lenses, so you really need large aperture to get both. Still, please specify what "look" exactly you want to achieve at the end

Comment: Until someone posts an answer, possibly see the Strobist post: ["Reverse Engineering Other Shooters' Light"](https://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/04/reverse-engineering-other-shooters.html).

Comment: @CrazyDino: In the moment I only have one system flash for my Fuji X-E2, and two old Vivitar 273, which have no possibility to regulate the power. I think I either have to rent or buy some equipment. I also have an old umbrella, but a new white one would not break the bank. to build two strip lights out of the vivitars could be more complicated, though...

Comment: @StephenG I know, she is using a Fuji setup and the portraits are done with wide angle lenses wide open. This is the part I understand by looking at the images, but thanks for your input. I could have been more precise in my question.

Comment: @mattdm I tried to narrow down the title and added a remark in the question... thanks for your hint

Comment: @aaaaaa plese also see my last comment. :)

Comment: @inkista Thanks for your input. I will study it ASAP

Comment: "Like these" *what*, though?

Comment: @mattdm you are right. I specified one certain image, to be precise. It's the one above the one with the CAT post it on the forehead.

Comment: No one can see that image when they see the headline. It's not helpful in search results or listings.

Comment: @mattdm: No one will ever see an image in a search result. I invite you to suggest a better headline if you are not satisfied by mine. You even could earn some more points by editing. ;)

Comment: @mattdm: Maybe I could include the image into the post, if it would be mine. But embedding an image I do not have any rights for, I guess this would be not the way to go.

Comment: Please read the link I posted above. You still have not *described* the look you want.

Comment: Maybe I am ignorant, or my ability to write English, which is not my mother tongue is far more limited than I thought. In edited the post to tell which image on the linked page I am talking about, I tagged it as [studio-lighting] and especially asked about it. I described a possible reverse engineered light setup. If you do not like the headline, please delete "Are color and tones in this seascape fine?" from your top posts, because it's as descriptive as my headline. I know, the question had been too vague in beginning, but I edited it to be more precise. I am still open for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Andreas, speculation but i will post it as an answer.

Having looked closely at the photo i believe it is a single light source. A large umbrella with diffuser or  octagonal soft box. I believe it is nearly straight on, close to the camera (slightly to camera right ) and the camera is close to the dog.

I think it is large, diffuse and close because of the quality of light, soft and no shadows under the chin or side of the face. The dog was far enough from the black background for the light to not be strong enough to register on the backdrop.

I see no evidence of a rim light on the back of the dogs head.

It could possibly be a ring light around the lens witch seems to be a wide angle, this would allow for the light to wrap around the dogs face nicely. But the reflection in the dogs eyes seems to indicate a larger light.

It is a general rule that a light or flash on camera  is not flattering or desirable lighting but she seems to have proven an exception to the rule.

Looking at the other shots i think she is using the same technique for her key light, a soft light on or very near the camera. some of the non black backgrounds seem to have a light, some seem to be just balanced with the key.

> As a side note, i did go to her web site. There is an option to sent her a message on her contact page, also an email address at the bottom of that page.

Comment: I fully agree with you regarding the large umbrella, octagonal soft box or whatever it is. thx